# Erlang- How to use Mnesia without records

Tags: database, functional-programming, erlang, erlang-otp, mnesia

From what I understand so far, Erlang records are tuples:

```
#myRecord{a="a", b="b"} = {myRecord, "a", "b"}
```

With this in mind, the following works:

```
mnesia:create_table({ attributes, [name, age] })
mnesia:activity(transaction, fun() -> mnesia:write(users, { user, "Charlie", "Unknow" }, write)
```

But how would I retrieve this entry?
Most of the Mnesia examples online use records to store and access table rows.

Comment: I would guess using `mensia:read/2` should work.
Whats the problem you see with the way you see in the examples? What have you tried?

Comment: I'd already tried mnesia:read/2, and it comes back with an empty list.

Comment: It's strange, because when I call observer:start from the shell and peak into the table, my test records are there.

Comment: mnesia:select/2 also appears not to work. I'm on Windows, btw. Would that make a difference?

Answer (score 3):

@Zeiss - You're right. mnesia:read/2 works. The problem was in me trying to use:

```
:mnesia.transaction(fn -> :mnesia.read(Users, b) end)
```

Instead of:

```
:mnesia.transaction(fn -> :mnesia.read(Users, "b") end)
```

Undoubtedly an elementary mistake.
Hope the answer helps out anyone else who runs into the same (or similar...) issue.

Comment: Good that you found this. :)